# Which Stack Exchange site to ask questions with subjective/opinionated answers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask programming-related questions which may have answers based on user's personal preference?

For example:

> What is the best IDE to use for building PHP based websites?

Comment: Try Quora. Stack Exchange doesn't like opinionated questions.

Comment: No, unfortunately such site doesn't exist. As of such questions on other sites would be voted to close as "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a StackExchange site where I can ask programming related questions which may have answers based on user's personal preference?

No, there isn't.

We found out (the hard way), that such questions don't promote a long lived community.

That is - experts flee from such sites after a while and they can become wastelands, where no one with actual knowledge contributes.

Comment: Just a small comment: Some big-list question survive on the network and the communities are happy about that. Getting to the state in which it works was the hard way, too, though :)

Comment: @yo' - "the hard way" is why those are the exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Seems overly harsh. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Not all subjective questions are barred from all sites.

Comment: @David - I am saying there isn't a _dedicated_ site for such questions (Not Programming Related started that way - anything goes, and very quickly changed its tune).